# Unable to connect to remote servers using wmi python

Tags: python, wmic

Iam writing a python code to connect to remote windows server using wmi.

When iam tring to connect to single machine with below line , am able to connect

```
conn = wmi.WMI("<ip>", user="", password="")
```

Whereas I need to connect to multiple servers using for loop by reading input from a text file containing the servers IP. In this case, am getting error as below

```
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemLocator', u'The RPC server is unavailable. ', None, 0, -2147023174), None)>
```

Comment: It sounds like one of the connections is failing in the `for` loop.  Have you tried connecting to just that one to see if there's something wrong with your connection credentials and/or the machine you're trying to connect to?  Also would be helpful to post the code for said `for` loop so people can better understand how you're connecting to multiple machines